# Javascript - undefined array element when adding eventlistener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am fairly new to javascript and I am trying to grab all the "td" elements in the DOM and add a click event to them. When the code finishes executing, i can see I have 37 elements in cells array, but when I click the element, I get "clicked td37 undefined" in my console statement no matter which element is clicked. I do not have a clue what is wrong and any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", createEventListeners, false);

function createEventListeners() {
   var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
   console.log(cells);

   for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
      cells[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      console.log("clicked td" +  i + " " + cells[i]);

      }, false);
   }

 }
</script>
```

Comment: you need to use IIFY to isolate the scope and pass the parameter i on the function signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the loop, the value of `i` will be the `cells.length`, so `cells[i]` is undefined. You need to wrap them in a function so that `i` is the value you want. Read more about closure [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```
function createEventListeners() {
  var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      cells[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("clicked td" +  i + " " + cells[i]);
      }, false);
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the assistance. This helps a lot and I will research closure in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

This is a scope issue. You need a closure. By the time any `Event` in your loop is called, `i` looks for it's last know value, which happens to be it's value at the end of the loop. Solution:

```
var pre = onload; // previous onload
onload = function(){
  if(pre)pre();
  function createEventListeners(){
    var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var i=0,l=cells.length; i<l; i++){
      (function(i){
        cells[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
          console.log('i is at position:'+i));
        }, false);
      })(i);
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', createEventListeners, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your loop, `i` is always the length of the array for anything you click on and since they're zero indexed, no element with that index exists. For example, if there are 10 elements, they're indexed as 0-9, but when you click any of them, `i` is always 10.

Answer (score 0):

This question+answers are a great example of when and how to use closures. Since this question is tagged with `jQuery`, the `each` function would be a way to do it in `jQuery`. When you use `each`, it conveniently closes over what you are eaching through, so this would also work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $tds = $('td');
    $tds.each(function (i, td) {
        $(td).click(function () {
            console.log(i, td);
        });
    });
});
```

And also,  there is a way to do it without closures. If you store the value of the iterator onto the element itself via a data attribute, it stores a copy of the value, rather than a reference, so it retains the value of `i` at the time it was assigned:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", createEventListeners, false);
function createEventListeners() {
    var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    console.log(cells);

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].setAttribute('data-i', i);
        cells[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            var i = this.getAttribute('data-i');
            console.log("clicked td" + i + " " + cells[i]);

        }, false);
    }
}
```